# Configure Sonar and maven to analyse multilingual project

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I wonder if it is possible to specify different languages in the sonar-project.properties file to analyse, for example, both java script and xml, which are in the same folder?

Thanks for your help!

---

### ADDITION

for example, I have the following project structure:

client
pom.xml
|
|-----UI
|-----pom.xml
|
|-----core
|-----pom.xml

In UI folder I have different types of files (js, html, xml) and maven java project in core folder. Can I aim sonar to UI folder so that it will check .js, .html and .xml files in this folder and subfolders recursivly? I tried to specify several languages (separated by comma) for one module, but that had no effect. Thanks!

---

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can check out the following "web+Javascrip" sample project: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-source-files-in-same-directory

Please not that there are some requirements on Sonar and Sonar Runner versions (described in the [README file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-source-files-in-same-directory/README.md)).

Comment: thanks, Fabrice, but what if I have a bit different situation? please, check out addition to the question.

Comment: I just realized, that project allows me to use maven only. Is it possible to make the same using maven?

Comment: That example uses Sonar-Runner. Is there an example that uses Maven? I have quite a big multi module Maven project and don't really want to put `sonar-project.properties` files everywhere.